# Flash ads not displaying in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, flash

I've been asked to look into an issue where flash ads are not displaying in IE.

The site, http://www.outbacktravelshop.com.au/ has a number of ads under the map in the right column. 5 of these are flash and these 5 flash ads do not show in IE (testing on a Windows 7 VM on IE9... also IE8 and IE7 via IETester). If you have a look at them in any other browser on PC or Mac they display.

Does anyone know why these may not be showing in IE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many people use [SWFObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) to embed flash as it deals with the various browser quirks for you.

You can then embed the Flash like this:

```
<script>

var flashvars = {};
var params = {};
var attributes = {};

swfobject.embedSWF("myContent.swf", "myContent", "300", "120", "9.0.0","expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried SWF object and get the same result.  The ads appear everywhere except for IE. I have also eliminated any javascript errors that IE was picking up incase this was causing an issue.